# PID changing when using ps --no-header command

Tags: linux, ps

When I user the tag --no-header or the = at the end of the column name the last PID always changes adding 1 to it.

Why does it change? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Compared to what? Is that a pid of `ps` itself?

Comment: Compared to showing headers

Comment: Isn't just the PID of each `ps` process incremented?

Comment: just the last, at least for my user processes